# rails update crud views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, crud

I'm a bit confused about how to update my views after adding columns to my database. I have an object that I needed to store extra info for and added columns to the database and ran the migration. I thought I'd have to update the views manually, but the new.html.erb has this:

```
<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', bids_path %>
```

I had created this object with `rails g scaffold Obj`. Is there a way to update the views so that the form includes all the information that i need for CRUD functionality. I know I could drop the table and destroy the scaffold and then generate a new scaffold with the new tables, but that doesn't seem like the right way to do things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

Renders the 'form' partial, which can be found in the same folder, named as _form.html.erb. Edit that file to add the new fields.

You can read more about Rails partials and layouts [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).